# Mysql installation on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, xampp, lampp

I am installing mysql on Ubuntu 16
when I use :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

it gives me :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-client is already the newest version (5.7.18-1ubuntu16.04).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-client : Depends: mysql-community-client (= 5.7.18-1ubuntu16.04) but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 5.7.18-1ubuntu16.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

how do I resolve this issue.

Comment: So, have you run `apt-get -f install`? What happens when you do?

Comment: Are you installing packages from mysql.com?  Probably you haven't added the mysql apt repository or haven't run apt-get update

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [ubuntu.se]